# In sonarqube - How to export issues to MS-Excel

Tags: sonarqube

Using SonarQube 4.3 version.

I'm trying to export the issues listed in sonar analysis to MS-Excel. 
Please help. I don't want to export to .html using report plugin.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this with the excel web-query.

1. Open an excel sheet and go to ***Data***-->select ***From Web*** from Get External Data section.
2. paste URL in ***Address*** section and click on ***GO*** button, here you can see your sonar report on the wizard.
3. click on ***Import*** then you will get a ***wizard*** to set ***properties***, set properties as you wish to set and hit ***OK***.
4. It brings all the data from the URL/`Sonar` to your excel sheet.
5. Take one new sheet and prepare table what all the things you want to highlight ex: Skipped Test cases/major/minor/coverage issues etc..
6. Finally with the excel formula `MATCH, INDEX, LEFT..` you can achieve this.

Hope it helps to prepare sonar statistics

Comment: It timed out. +1 for the details.

Comment: Sonar needs authentication. I tried setting cookies in the header etc. but still not able to get the report